# Base R Choropleth: colors aren't being applied to the map according to the order of the interval/breaks which makes the map hard to read

Tags: r, shapefile, choropleth, rgdal

I created a choropleth with base R but I'm struggling with the colors. First, the colors don't follow the same order as the intervals and second, two of the intervals are using the same color, all of which makes the graph hard to read. This happens regardless of how many colors I use. It also doesn't matter whether I'm using brewer.pal or base colors.[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMeIY.jpg) is a map with its respective legend illustrating the issue.

Below are the statements that I use to create the graph once data has been downloaded:

**#Relevant packages:**

```
library(dplyr)
    library(RColorBrewer)
    library(rgdal)
```

**#create colors vector**

```
pop_colors <- brewer.pal(8,"Purples")
```

**#create breaks/intervals**

```
pop_breaks <- c(0,20000,40000,60000,80000,100000,120000)
```

**#apply breaks to population**

```
cuts <- cut(cal_pop$Pop2016, pop_breaks, dig.lab = 6)
```

**#create a vector with colors by population according to the interval they belong to:**

```
color_breaks <- pop_colors[findInterval(cal_pop$Pop2016,vec = pop_breaks)]
```

**Create choropleth**

```
plot(cal_pop,col = color_breaks, main = "Calgary Population (2016)")
```

**#create legend**

```
legend("topleft", fill = color_breaks, legend = levels(cuts), title = "Population")
```

I used readOGR() command to read the shape file, which I'm linking [here](https://usaupload.com/1juD) in case anybody is interested in taking a look at the data.

I'd appreciate any advice you could give me.
Thanks!

Comment: The shapefile you provide is not valid and the problem is thus not reproducible. Can you provide part of the data using `dput()`?

Comment: Sure, this is the population data:
[1]  88539  68045  53586  63302  39747 110327 103904 117654  92397  74111  86443 114269 105409  40982  20056  43334
[17]  41769  63137  24097  60434  34253  26450

Comment: Length: 
 [1]  41316.22  43102.14  31279.65  21491.84  34562.10  57902.87  54746.88  59176.86  41702.64  27987.53  26664.65
[12]  39140.56  43052.23  23300.63  22598.76 138748.31 199403.50  74400.42 117409.08  50646.82 476439.48 761550.90

Comment: Area:
[1]   48941780   75123001   23255709   20378821   25807650   66261535   78256982  135771194   91280690   43721875
[11]   28744884   66790819   76811291   15772621   11185083  477009662  765397605  181289084  302604998   40099320
[21] 5902129285 9114670885

Comment: @knytt Sure, this is the population data:
[1]  88539  68045  53586  63302  39747 110327 103904 117654  92397  74111  86443 114269 105409  40982  20056  43334
[17]  41769  63137  24097  60434  34253  26450

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in this line:

```
color_breaks <- pop_colors[findInterval(cal_pop$Pop2016,vec = pop_breaks)]
```

I can't read your data file, so I'll use a built-in one from the sf package.

```
library(sf)
nc <- readOGR(system.file("shapes/", package="maptools"), "sids")
str(nc@data)

colors <- brewer.pal(8,"Purples")

#create breaks/intervals    
sid_breaks <- c(0,2,4,6,8,10,12,20,60)

#apply breaks to population    
sid_cuts <- cut(nc$SID79, sid_breaks, dig.lab = 6, include=TRUE)

#create a vector with colors by population according to the interval they belong to:
sid_colors <- colors[sid_cuts]

#Create choropleth    
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(nc, col = sid_colors)
legend("bottomleft", fill = colors, legend = levels(sid_cuts), nc=2, title = "SID (1979)", bty="n")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed the statement but the problem persists. Do you think it's possible that the problem lies in the format of the file or an active statement I'm not aware of?
Something I noticed is that the colors might be being applied according to the order of values in the cuts vector and not according to the levels of said vector, but I'm not sure how to proceed if this is the case.

Comment: Did you follow my commands? I already mentioned where your problem lies. Your legend command is also incorrect. You need `fill=pop_colors`.

Comment: I had followed your commands at first, but didn't realize that my legend fill was also off. Thanks so much, it worked!